# Backing up specific directory with it's content to remote location

Tags: backup

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04, hosted on ovh and accessed to remotely through PuTTy (Terminal only, NO GUI).

My intention is to backup a single directory containing a running server, with all it's sub-files/directories towards a remote location where various backups would be stored (Up to a limit).

- How often?: At least every 24h.
- Remotely where?: Not sure, Some external service like Google Drive It may depend on how it's done. Free + More space is best.
- Restoration processes are unnecessary, all I'd like is for that directory to be sent to a remote location where it can later be manually examined/recovered in case of any damage to the main OS or files.
- I don't need to backup the whole system, just that directory and it's content.

What I've already checked:

- Ubuntu's main guide for "BackupYourSystem" I still felt like I had to ask 
  here as I'm fairly new.
- Some of the programs listed on that guide, and other tutorials which I wasn't
  entirely convinced by.

Could I get some advice on how to do this? I'm one week new to ubuntu. Thanks!
Any further information needed I will gladly provide.

Comment: When you say "a single file", do you in fact mean a single _directory_?

Comment: Yes, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to research `rsync`. Start with

```
man rsync
```

It is a tool made for the kind of backups you want to implement.

For your use case it should be as simple as running

```
rsync -av --progress <user>@<host>:<directory> .
```

from the machine and location where you want the backup.

Comment: Thanks for the info Bex!
Seeing that command though, I wonder about a few things like:
- Where can I get the exact parameters for "user", "host" and "directory" from my google drive account?
- How can I schedule this command to be executed once every 24h, and still being that specific file?
- Is that final dot in the command also required?

Still, I will try to make sense of what the man rsync documentation is telling me.

Comment: @Mithrandir I fail to find any reference to Google Drive in the question. Do you want to backup content stored on Google Drive, or do you want to keep the backup there?

Comment: I want to send a copy of the directory there (Preferebly) every 24h.
Each daily copy should just get stored there, If possible, up to a limit, after which the latest would be removed by the newest backup.

Answer (score 0):

To remotely use Google Drive from the command line, you can use the [REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) with the `curl` command.

tar and zip your directory like so:

```
tar -jcf backup.tar.bz2 <directory>
```

send it to Google Drive with

```
curl -d @backup.tar.bz2 https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files --header "Content-Type:application/x-tar"
```

To do this, you need an authorization token - read about that in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-auth).

You need to modify the `curl` example above with the authentication.

Once this is done, and you have tested it, put it into a script. Once *that* is done, to run it periodically, use `crontab`. Check with

```
man crontab
```

then edit your `crontab` entry with

```
crontab -e
```

Comment: Ok, this sounds promising.
However, I can't just zip the main file, because it has a server running inside of it. I need to copy the directory locally somewhere else, then zip it, then send it. But I also need to delete the locally zipped file only after it's done sending it (So the local zipped files don't accumulate), I wonder if I can make the script wait untill it's been sent and then delete it... I guess I'll have to learn some scripting.

Looks like quite a challenge for a newbie like me, but I'll do my best, I'll tel you how it goes hahaha

Comment: I made some progress with this:
First of all, I created some credentials on the google drive API, and downloaded a json file which seems to contain some access stuff (Is this what I need?). What part/s of it should I add to the curl command?
Can the zip name "backup.tar.bz2" be changed? Or is this specific name required? Can I generate the zip on the same directory as the file I just copied? If I change this directory, should I also specify the full path after the @ on the curl command?
Lot of questions really, but my experience on this is 0. I got it up to zipping at least.

Comment: @Mithrandir Very good, well done so far. You have a lot of questions yet, and that's a good thing. Research as far as you can, and then pose them as new questions here on the site. That's exactly the kind of spirit that keeps this site going.